# Ignore spurious focus events for after-focus-change-function

Tags: gui-emacs, focus, emacs27

I'm on Emacs 27.1, Fedora 33, GNOME 3.38.2.

In the latest `NEWS` it is reported that

> The hooks `focus-in-hook` and `focus-out-hook` are now obsolete.
> Instead, attach to `after-focus-change-function` using `add-function`
> and inspect the focus state of each frame using `frame-focus-state`.

The documentation for `after-focus-change-function` says

> Depending on window system, focus events may also be delivered
> repeatedly and with different focus states before settling to the
> expected values.  Code relying on focus notifications should
> "debounce" any user-visible updates arising from focus changes,
> perhaps by deferring work until redisplay.

Indeed, after evaluating this code,

```
(defun focus-test ()
  (message "ffs: %s" (frame-focus-state)))
(add-function :after after-focus-change-function #'focus-test)
```

every time I switch buffer by selecting one with the mouse my message buffer shows

```
ffs: nil
ffs: t
ffs: nil
ffs: t
```

That is, Emacs sees two back and forth focus changes where I did none, and most importantly it has hallucinations of focus-out events which defeat the usefulness of the `after-focus-change-function`+`frame-focus-state` method for triggering functions based on focus events.

My question is, how do I "'debounce' any user-visible updates arising from focus changes"? (I made a naive attempt with

```
(defun focus-test ()
  (sit-for 0)
  (message "ffs: %s" (frame-focus-state)))
```

but it didn't work.)

Comment: If you don't get a satisfactory answer here, maybe consider filing a bug report, if you think there might be a bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. Some have mentioned frame-focus problems introduced with Emacs 27.

Comment: I've asked on https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2021-01/msg00328.html and also on https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/kxsgtn/ignore_spurious_focus_events_for/. If I get an answer I'll copy it here.

Comment: Great. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I've settled with these home-made remakes of the obsoleted hooks:

```lisp
;; Set up hooks to be run on focus in and focus out

;; Mutter sends spurious focus events, including sending focus out
;; events when Emacs never really was unfocused.
;; The timer filters out these false focus out events, while
;; checking the ‘last-focus-state’ allows ignoring repeated events
;; of the same kind.
;; REVIEW: false focus out events are still received sometimes when
;; using the menu bar.
;; Based on a suggestion by DasEwigeLicht on
;; https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/kxsgtn/ignore_spurious_focus_events_for/

(defvar focus-events-timer nil)

(defvar last-focus-state (frame-focus-state))

(defvar my-focus-in-hook nil
  "Normal hook run when all frames lose input focus.")

(defvar my-focus-out-hook nil
  "Normal hook run when a frame gains focus.")

(defun change-of-focus-functions ()
  (unless (equal last-focus-state (frame-focus-state))
    (if (frame-focus-state)
        (run-hooks 'my-focus-in-hook)
      (run-hooks 'my-focus-out-hook)))
  (setq focus-events-timer nil)
  (setq last-focus-state (frame-focus-state)))

(defun run-change-of-focus-functions-with-timer ()
  (unless (timerp focus-events-timer)
    (setq focus-events-timer
          (run-at-time "0.05 sec" nil ; Delay chosen by trial and error. Test it if you change it.
                       #'change-of-focus-functions))))

(add-function :after after-focus-change-function #'run-change-of-focus-functions-with-timer)

;; Test

(defun focus-in-test ()
  (message "focus-in"))

(defun focus-out-test ()
  (message "focus-out"))

(add-hook 'my-focus-in-hook #'focus-in-test)
(add-hook 'my-focus-out-hook #'focus-out-test)

;; Actual use

(add-hook 'my-focus-out-hook #'do-auto-save)
```